# Saving raw request & response of Soap test step in user defined path

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to save soap test step raw request & step in a path which is read from configuration file imported in test suite custom properties.

How can I do that?

Using the below script but with fixed location that was defined in the script.

```
def myOutFile = "D:/TestLog/Online_Test/PostPaidSuccess_Payment_BillInqReq.x‌​ml" 
def response = context.expand( '${BillInq#Request}' ) 
def f = new File(myOutFile) 
f.write(response, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: def myOutFile = "D:/TestLog/Online_Test/PostPaidSuccess_Payment_BillInqReq.xml"
def response = context.expand( '${BillInq#Request}' )
def f = new File(myOutFile)
f.write(response, "UTF-8")

Comment: Are you sure to store raw request alone using configured value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to avoid additional `Groovy Script` test step to just store previous step request / response.

Below script assumes that, there is user defined property (`REQUEST_PATH`) at test suite level with its value(valid file path to store data, path separated by forward slash '/' even on windows).

Instead use `Script Assertion` for the `Billing` request step itself(one more step less in the test case)

```
//Stores raw request to given location using utf-8 encoding
new File(context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('REQUEST_PATH') as String).write(context.rawRequest,'utf-8')
```

Actually  there is a small difference between `context.request` and `context.rawRequest` and the above script using `rawRequest`.

`context.request` - will have the variables as it is, not the actual value.

For eg:

```
<element>${java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()}</element>
```

Where  as `context.rawRequest` - will have the actual value that was sent in the request.

For eg:

```
<element>4ee36185-9bfb-47d2-883e-65bf6d3d616b</element>
```

**EDIT** Based on comments: Please try this for `ACCESS DENIED` issue

```
def file = new File(context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('REQUEST_PATH') as String)
if (!file.canWrite()) {
    file.writable = true
}
file.write(context.rawRequest,'utf-8')
```

**EDIT2** Based on further comments from OP, the request file name should be the current test step name.

```
//Create filename by concatenating path from suite property and current test stepname
def filename = "${context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('REQUEST_PATH')}/${context.currentStep.name}.xml" as String
new File(filename).write(context.rawRequest,'utf-8')
```

Comment: Have you defined test suite level custom property `REQUEST_PATH` and its value? have you used `rawRequest`? what happens if you have `log.info context.rawRequest` in the script? Does it show response?

Comment: yes i defined Request path property value and now iam getting access denied error

Comment: How did the nullpoint go? Hope you are following the answer thoroughly. You had this same error in previous question too and not sure how that was resolved. This is something very peculiar in your environment. Can you share the log from error.log?

Comment: ERROR:java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\TestLog\Online_Test (Access is denied)
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\TestLog\Online_Test (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.newWriter(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1637)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.newWriter(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1658)
    at

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.write(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$862.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at Script27.run(Script27.groovy:1)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Was the parent directory present? where is the file extension?

Comment: D:\TestLog\Online_Test but they are files not 1 file so each one will be with soap test step name and suppose to be in xml formal

Comment: what is the value at `RESOURCE_PATH`

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad, Have you set `D:/TestLog/Online_Test/PostPaidSuccess_Payment_BillInqReq.x‌​ml` in `RESOURCE_PATH` in test suite properties? can you try the updated answer ? See the below EDIT for access denied error?

Comment: D:/TestLog/Online_Test

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad, for `RESOURCE_PATH`, have the same value as `myOutFile` that you have in the your script i.e., `D:/TestLog/Online_Test/PostPaidSuccess_Payment_BillInqReq.x‌‌​​ml`. You can save the file using directory name which why you getting error.

Comment: but i want to save automatically with each test step name per test case

Comment: Which you are mention it now? not earlier. Let me update. By the way it would have been appreciated if you at least try the solution as it is once before doing your own changes. Would it not be the problem if you run the test multiple times?

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad, please see the updated answer `EDIT2`. Note that if you run the test multiple times, it may overwrite the existing file. I believe that it should also help your previous question while saving the file.

Comment: i tried and still getting access denied issue                             Thu ERROR:java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\TestLog\Online_Test (Access is denied)
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\TestLog\Online_Test (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.newWriter(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1637)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.newWriter(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1658)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.write(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$862.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:5)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

Comment: Really sorry, you do not seem to show or try exactly what is provided in first place and mixing your own stuff. There are two lines in the given script, it is showing in your log that line 5 has problem. Please show screen shot. Making simple things more complicated.

Comment: def file = new File(context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('TESTLOG') as String)
if (!file.canWrite()) {
    file.writable = true
}
file.write(context.rawRequest,'utf-8')

Comment: @MarwaAbdelgawad So, you did not pick the script from answer `EDIT2`? where it appends current test step name to the path. I suggest you to `carefully` read the answers or comments. You making the same errors repeatedly.

Comment: where TESTLOG is the property name and value is D:/TestLog/Online_Test and suppose to complete it with test step name.testcase name.xml